# I cant import libraries in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cocos2d-x

I'm practicing in cocos2d-x and I want to make a transition from scena using  a button, I have my  NewScene in a file with their respective .h and .cpp. i imported the file into the main but when I try to run it I get the following error

```
CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp.o: In function 
`HelloWorld::Play(cocos2d::Ref*)': /home/ankur/Documents/cocos2d-x-3.2/menu
/MyGame/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:62: undefined reference to 
`NewScene::createScene()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[2]: * [bin/MyGame] Error 1 make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all] 
Error 2 make: * [all] Error 2 Error running command, return code: 2
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

el codigo de HelloWorldScene.cpp es el siguiente:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "NewScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;
....
void HelloWorld::Play(cocos2d::Ref *pSender)
{
CCLOG("Play");

auto scene = NewScene::createScene();

Director::getInstance()->pushScene(scene);
}

void HelloWorld::Highscores(cocos2d::Ref *pSender)
{
CCLOG("Highscores");

auto scene = NewScene::createScene();

Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
```

}

and NewScebe.h is :

```
 #ifndef __NEW_SCENE_H__
 #define __NEW_SCENE_H__

 #include "cocos2d.h"

 class NewScene : public cocos2d::Layer
 {
 public:
// there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

// Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
virtual bool init();  

// a selector callback
void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

// implement the "static create()" method manually
CREATE_FUNC(NewScene);

cocos2d::Sprite *mySprite;

void GoBack(Ref *pSender);
void GoBack2(Ref *pSender);

};

 #endif // __NEW_SCENE_H__
```

the   files are in the same folder as my main so I don't understand why it  can't read them

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the library as well as include the appropriate headers. The library should have documentation on how to do this for your platform.

Comment: I am using c ++ library with cocos2d-x this example it out of a tutorial. so far I have not seen another tutorial do something different from what I have

Comment: Well your error is because you didn't link to the library or you did it wrongly. Update the post with your linker flags.